# R removing data based upon % in another dataframe

Tags: r

I have two data frames (example data shown below). DF1 provides species abundance across plots, DF2 shows the traits of species from DF1. However, some of the plots in DF1 have a number of species that are not in the trait dataset.

I would like to remove plots ID's ("PlotObservationID") from DF1 which have 30% or more "Species" that are not in the trait data (DF2). Species names across both datasets are identicle.

Would anyone have any advice on how to do this in R?

Thank you in advance.

DF1 (Species abundance)

| Species | PlotObservationID | Abun |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Agrostis capillaris | 34475 | 0.098361 |  |  |
| Agrostis vinealis | 34475 | 0.016393 |  |  |
| Carex bigelowii | 34475 | 0.016393 |  |  |
| Deschampsia cespitosa | 34475 | 0.52459 |  |  |
| Empetrum nigrum | 34475 | 0.098361 |  |  |
| Viola palustris | 34475 | 0.011236 |  |  |
| Agrostis capillaris | 34476 | 0.067416 |  |  |
| Anthoxanthum odoratum | 34476 | 0.011236 |  |  |
| Nardus stricta | 34476 | 0.359551 |  |  |
| Salix herbacea | 34476 | 0.011236 |  |  |
| Salix phylicifolia | 34476 | 0.011236 |  |  |
| Vaccinium uliginosum | 34476 | 0.359551 |  |  |
| Viola palustris | 34476 | 0.011236 |  |  |
| Agrostis capillaris | 34477 | 0.011236 |  |  |
| Agrostis vinealis | 34477 | 0.067416 |  |  |
| Carex bigelowii | 34477 | 0.359551 |  |  |
| Vaccinium uliginosum | 34477 | 0.016393 |  |  |
| Viola palustris | 34477 | 0.098361 |  |  |

DF2 (Traits)

| Species | SLA | PlantHeight | SeedMass | LDMC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Agrostis capillaris | 3.2 | 1.08 | 2.86 | 1.23 |
| Agrostis vinealis | 2.8 | 1.2 | 3.11 | 1.12 |
| Carex bigelowii | 2.6 | 1.92 | 0.88 | 0.98 |
| Deschampsia cespitosa | 2.3 | 0.56 | 1.57 | 1.1 |
| Empetrum nigrum | 2.3 | 1.37 | 0.22 | 0.96 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could group by 'PlotObservationID' and get the `mean` of logical vector for `filter`ing out those ids with 30% or more Species not found

```
library(dplyr)
DF1 %>% 
  group_by(PlotObservationID) %>%
  filter(mean(!Species %in% DF2$Species) < 0.3) %>% 
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  Species               PlotObservationID   Abun
  <chr>                             <int>  <dbl>
1 Agrostis capillaris               34475 0.0984
2 Agrostis vinealis                 34475 0.0164
3 Carex bigelowii                   34475 0.0164
4 Deschampsia cespitosa             34475 0.525 
5 Empetrum nigrum                   34475 0.0984
6 Viola palustris                   34475 0.0112
```

#### data

```
DF1 <- structure(list(Species = c("Agrostis capillaris", "Agrostis vinealis", 
"Carex bigelowii", "Deschampsia cespitosa", "Empetrum nigrum", 
"Viola palustris", "Agrostis capillaris", "Anthoxanthum odoratum", 
"Nardus stricta", "Salix herbacea", "Salix phylicifolia", "Vaccinium uliginosum", 
"Viola palustris", "Agrostis capillaris", "Agrostis vinealis", 
"Carex bigelowii", "Vaccinium uliginosum", "Viola palustris"), 
    PlotObservationID = c(34475L, 34475L, 34475L, 34475L, 34475L, 
    34475L, 34476L, 34476L, 34476L, 34476L, 34476L, 34476L, 34476L, 
    34477L, 34477L, 34477L, 34477L, 34477L), Abun = c(0.098361, 
    0.016393, 0.016393, 0.52459, 0.098361, 0.011236, 0.067416, 
    0.011236, 0.359551, 0.011236, 0.011236, 0.359551, 0.011236, 
    0.011236, 0.067416, 0.359551, 0.016393, 0.098361)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))

DF2 <- structure(list(Species = c("Agrostis capillaris", "Agrostis vinealis", 
"Carex bigelowii", "Deschampsia cespitosa", "Empetrum nigrum"
), SLA = c(3.2, 2.8, 2.6, 2.3, 2.3), PlantHeight = c(1.08, 1.2, 
1.92, 0.56, 1.37), SeedMass = c(2.86, 3.11, 0.88, 1.57, 0.22), 
    LDMC = c(1.23, 1.12, 0.98, 1.1, 0.96)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```